# Can't power off, irqs disabled, daemon service

Tags: boot, partitioning, shutdown, systemd, services

First of all I m sorry if my problem has been solved somewhere else I didn't notice, please know I tried.

So I recently bought the Erazer Crawler E30e, and I want to have Ubuntu 22.04 as my main OS (I don't want windows at all).
So to install it I used a bootable key with Rufus, and partitioned my computer with :

- a swap part with 8000 Mo
- Root part with 70000 Mo (something like that)
- Home part with 200000 Mo (something like that)
- tmp part with 6000 Mo
- fat32 part with 1000 Mo (something like that)
- EFI part with 500 Mo

This time it kind of works, but when I restarted the computer after the installation, it got stuck after "[ OK ] Reached target System Reboot" (I will try to give some pictures)
It was the kind of stuck where you could still write things, Ctrl + C appears as "^C^[^" (or something like that) but can't type any command whatsoever. Basically you are stuck and you computer probably is too.
So I had to force power off the computer. And upon restarting, everything seemed to work, session was here, desktop is here, internet works everything, but I m still forced to force power off.
And while it didn't always reacted like that, I always had to force power off the computer, no matter what the situation was.

When I didn't use the fat32 and tmp part, I couldn't even get to the desktop or the part where you select the user and you put your password. I sometimes got stuck in an infinite loading screen with erazer on top and ubuntu under, with the loading thingy turning around for probably an infinite amount of time.
When I didn't get stuck with the infinite loading screen, I got the same situation as the "Reached Target Reboot System" thing I said earlier, but with "systemd-udevd exited with irqs disabled", this is actually the error that came back the most.

Also sometimes when I restart the computer to finish my Ubuntu installation, I often had a terminal screen which stayed for something around 3 seconds showing a few errors that went like "[FAILED] Failed to start ZSYS daemon service." written multiple times (from the research I made it doesn't look like its a big problem, but still it bothers me)

I m sorry I m very imprecise, I will go to the shop where I bought it this week and see if they can help me, but its nothing really abnormal and I just don't know how to do research.

to sum up I tried :

- Ctrl+C and writing exit every time I got stuck somewhere.
- Redo the Partitioning part again and again by changing tiny things.
- powering it off and waiting.

I also just checked something called Openrazer, I don't know if its really useful for me, but it mentions daemon so idk. I m sending the link here (https://openrazer.github.io/).

And finally to sum it up, I can't power off my computer except if I force power off, I don't know if I still have these errors but I "failed" to start the ZSYS daemon service and my systemd sometimes happens to exit with my irqs disabled.

I will try to send pictures asap.

[Its the systemd error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHY6w.jpg)

[Reached target reboot system screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3mFW.jpg)

[Failed to start ZSYS daemon service screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcU2B.jpg)

Comment: As you mentioned in the last paragraph providing links to screenshots would help.